# Unable to run npm commands

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, registry, command-prompt

Im using a windows 11 machine, and whenever i execute `npm install` or `npm --version` or any npm command it gives me errors like this

`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
`/F was unexpected at this time.`

I am attaching the snapshot of the terminal as well here.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQcTk.png)

I thought maybe something is wrong with my command prompt but when I run other commands like `java --version` or `git --version` they execute properly.

What could be the issue? is it something to do with my windows registy? Please help

Comment: check if you have installed nodejs by running `node -v` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. So I am putting it up here for others.
The problem was the windows registry. After changing the value of `EnableExtensions` to 1 in regedit -> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`, it started working.